# What does struts 1 do when passed null values?

Tags: java, jsp, struts

I'm updating code in an old Java application at work but I'm pretty new to Struts 1 and I was wondering what the framework does when it see's a null value in a form that's trying to be accessed by the JSP?

- Does it convert null to the string null?
- Or does it leave the field in the JSP blank?
- Or does it fall over and fail?

Thanks for any insight into this,

Alexei Blue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your question is related to the null handling behavior in Struts 1 tags. Most of these tags will throw a `RuntimeException` if one of their supplied arguments is null, but you can often override this behavior by setting their `ignore` attribute to false. Here is an example using `bean:write`:

```
<bean:write name="employee" property="firstName" ignore="true"/>
```

In this case a blank field will be written if the `employee` bean is null.

You can also test for null values explicitly using `logic:notEmpty`.

Comment: Thanks for that Perception :)